# HTML 5 apple smooth Stream for remote IIS manager

Tags: iis, video-streaming, windows-server-2008, iis-manager, windows-media-services

Hi i am trying to stream video from IIS 7 to my iOS application with Transform Manager.

Tutorial Link : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StreamingLiveOrOnDemandVideoFromIIS7ToIOSDevicesIPhoneiPadAndSilverlightClients.aspx

I have create an IIS virtual directory to output directory of the Transform Manager. Index.html that is created in AppleOutput folder for iOS streaming and When I open it from my local machine video doesn't play in my safari, chrome or iOS browser. Is there any IIS settings i have to enable to stream videos out of my remote server

Here is the code thats generated

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>iOS Streaming page for xhaO6UhGMU-m3u8-aapl...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video autoplay="true" controls="true" src="xhaO6UhGMU-m3u8-aapl.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)">xhaO6UhGMU-m3u8-aapl</video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Apple Output Direcotry
[image]

Here is my Virtual Directory i am accessing from local machine but video won't play

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions:

1. Do you have IIS Web Publishing turned on?
2. Is the AppleOutput folder you're referencing in the inetpub\wwwroot directory?

By default, the Transform Manager watch folder is outside of the web root. Any Smooth Streaming conversions will need to be moved into a directory available from within the web root.